# Javascript, NodeJS and making a login post request to a webserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Please excuse my inexperience in this area as I ask this question. I come from a C++ background, and my experience with web technologies is quite limited.

I want to understand how to obtain some debugging information about the request my browser makes to a websever login page.

I want to be able to reproduce this request using Node JS and Javascript - most likely using the `https` package, which I believe is native to Javascript now.

I understand that if I point my browser to the web server login page, eg `www.myserver.local/login` the browser makes a `GET` request to obtain some html and maybe javascript code. I assume that when I enter my username and password, the browser makes a `POST` request, sending the username and password to the webserver, which must then return some data like a cookie which I can use for subsequent requests to prove that I have completed the login/authentication process.

If my understanding of any of the above is wrong please let me know.

Where I am stuck at the moment is I don't know how to obtain the information about the `POST` request which my browser makes to the server to complete the login process.

Can I access this information using something like Google Chrome? I would assume browsers provide some way of obtaining debug information which would contain a log of the requests made and allow a developer to inspect them.

If I am wrong about that, is there an alternative way I can reverse-engineer this process to understand how to construct my request?

I'm quite new to all of this so any helpful pointers in the right direction would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. That is not how the process works for every website, but is commonplace nonetheless.

If you are using Google Chrome, you can use Chrome DevTools to follow network activity. Long-story short, in Chrome, you can right click anywhere on a page and choose "Inspect" to open DevTools. You can read more about Chrome DevTools [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/).

Firefox offers a similar tool, named Firefox DevTools. You can read more about that [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/). Safari does too: https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/.

The modern way of performing HTTP requests in JavaScript is with the asynchronous [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

A piece of advice: As you are coming from a statically typed language, JavaScript may be confusing (or rather, annoying). Definitely check out TypeScript at some point. It is the way of the world.

Comment: I know about the Inspect feature - or at least how to get to it. I don't know much about how to use it however. How would I actually view the data sent and recieved?

Comment: Google provides detailed instructions on the page I linked: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/. Did you visit it before commenting?

Comment: Ok yes I've found it now thanks

Comment: Great! Please let me know if you have any other questions.